# Can I feed an orphaned baby rat cows milk? And how would I do that?

Tags: diet, feeding, rat

I found an orphaned baby rat, they're small enough that their eyes aren't even open yet, and I don't want to let the little thing die, but I only have access to cow's milk, and I can't go anywhere to get any other formula or something. Can I use said cows milk? And how would I feed them?

Comment: So how did you do?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to feed the baby rat kitten milk replacement formula, or a soy based human replacement formula ([see link](https://www.pittsburghratloversclub.org/important-links/how-to-feed-orphaned-baby-rats-or-mice)) The best way to feed is every 3-4 hours using a very small plastic syringe.